# xgboost and its sklearn's integration feature_importances_ error

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

I'm using `XGBoost` and its `sklearn`'s wrapper.

Whenever I try to print `feature_importances_` it comes with the following error:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10

Digging into the code I found out that the `feature_importances_` [property](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/python-package/xgboost/sklearn.py#L492) is calling `get_fscore` [method](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/03dfffca1589b4486119eb23319b4ed76eae4a0b/python-package/xgboost/core.py#L1008) (**with empty params**) from original booster. This method explicitly returns a dictionary shaped like this:

```
{'feat_name1':5,'feat_name2':8,...,'feat_nameN':1}
```

So, taking into account that `feature_importances_` applies an `int` conversion to the keys uncovers the **error's message** rationale.

```
keys = [int(k.replace('f', '')) for k in fs.keys()] #this is the conflictive line of code
```

So, my question here is two-folded:

1- **is this a bug** and therefore I should report it (or even fix it and request a pull)?

2- is there something I'm missing with the `get_fscore` function and its `fmap` param?

Comment: were you able to get the column names from the `feature_importances_` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest to report it as a bug at the XGBoost Github site: https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues